# Really confused with unit vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

1. Let $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ be linearly independent unit vectors. Find the set of all possible values of $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}$. Give your answer in interval notation.
2. What is the maximum possible length of the vector resulting from the following linear combination?
   $$
   \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_1} \|} \,\mathbf{v_1} + \frac{1}{\|\mathbf{v_2}\|} \,\mathbf{v_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\| \mathbf{v_n} \|} \,\mathbf{v_n}
   $$

So far I have gotten nowhere with this problem and I cant even look at a similar problem in the textbook. If someone can help me i would really appreciate it.

Comment: $\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}=|\vec{u}||\vec v|\cos \alpha=\cos\alpha \in (a,b)$ where $a,b$ are ...

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, this formula is very useful: $u \cdot v = |u||v|\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors.

For the second problem, call this combination $V$.  The length is given by
$$|V| = \sqrt{V \cdot V}$$.  Expand the dot product like you would with a polynomial.  The self-similar terms will give $\frac{1}{||v_i||^2}v_i \cdot v_i = 1$, while the cross terms will give $\frac{v_i \cdot v_j}{|v_i||v_j|} = \cos(\theta_{ij})$.  Now, how can we maximize these angles?

Comment: How are we supposed to maximize it?

Comment: Well, the cosine is maximized when the vectors point in the same direction.  See @J.G's answer.

Comment: so the maximum would be n?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For part 1, linear independence ensures $u\cdot v\ne\pm1$, so the possible values comprise an open interval $(-1,\,1)$ instead of the closed $[-1,\,1]$. For part 2, you've summed $n$ unit vectors, so by the triangle inequality the maximum possible length is $n$, achieved when the vectors are all parallel as opposed to being antiparallel.